# How to use Session Variable inside the Thread(Background process ) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, session, caching

I have an Issue in Storing data in **Session** inside the **Thread(Background Process)**

```
 DataTable dtmultifamilyurlvalues = new DataTable();
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("FamilyHomes");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("AllListiedCurrent");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("AllListiedTrend");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("BottomCurrent");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("BottomTrend");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("LowerCurrent");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("LowerTrend");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("UpperCurrent");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("UpperTrend");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("TopCurrent");
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Columns.Add("TopTrend");

                    //House Size
                    dtmultifamilyurlvalues.Rows.Add("Median House Size", Getmedian(familtypevalue, "a", "Sqft:MEDIAN"), GetTrends(familtypevalue, "a", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend") + " " + GetTrends(familtypevalue, "a", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend_strength"),
                        Getmedian(familtypevalue, "b", "Sqft:MEDIAN"), GetTrends(familtypevalue, "b", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend") + " " + GetTrends(familtypevalue, "b", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend_strength"),
                        Getmedian(familtypevalue, "l", "Sqft:MEDIAN"), GetTrends(familtypevalue, "l", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend") + " " + GetTrends(familtypevalue, "l", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend_strength"),
                        Getmedian(familtypevalue, "u", "Sqft:MEDIAN"), GetTrends(familtypevalue, "u", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend") + " " + GetTrends(familtypevalue, "u", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend_strength"),
                        Getmedian(familtypevalue, "t", "Sqft:MEDIAN"), GetTrends(familtypevalue, "t", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend") + " " + GetTrends(familtypevalue, "t", "Sqft:MEDIAN_trend_strength"));


 HttpContext.Current.Session["datatablevalues"] = dtmultifamilyurlvalues;
 //HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("multifamilyAltos", dtmultifamilyurlvalues,null,System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 60), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,null);
                });
            Multifamily.IsBackground = true;
            Multifamily.Start();
```

This Through an error object reference error,

And I had used HttpRuntime.Cache also but when i run in two systems it produces same results it should be different based on the input(I think it is overriding the value)

And i searched to web and know that httpcontext can't be work inside the Thread.

So,Please tell me a solution for this Issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data= SynchronizationContext.Current;


Task t = Task.Run(() => {

    string sessionValue = null;

    data.Post(() => {

        sessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["value"];
    }


});
```

Comment: Thanks but,I need to Store Datatable to Session variable